# Redirected Standard Output Data ">"

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I thought this would be pretty straight-forward, but I'm having problems with the Process class and redirected stdout. I'm trying to run a java program (Craftbukkit, Minecraft server software) and redirect the output.

Everything works correctly for the first two lines

```
210 recipes
27 achievements
```

but after that line every line that follows is simply ">"

```
>
>
>
>
>
```

Correct output should look like this

```
210 recipes
27 achievements
20:52:45 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.4.6
20:52:45 [INFO] Loading properties
20:52:45 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
20:52:45 [INFO] Generating keypair
20:52:46 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
20:52:48 [INFO] This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.4.6-R0.3
-5-g82c58b5-b2589jnks (MC: 1.4.6) (Implementing API version 1.4.6-R0.4-SNAPSHOT)

20:52:49 [INFO] Preparing level "world"
```

I put in a breakpoint to see what the value of e.Data was, type string, value ">". So the issue is not with outputting.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServerProcess p = new ServerProcess("craftbukkit.jar");
}

class ServerProcess
{

    public ServerProcess(string server_jar)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", "-jar " + server_jar);
        pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = pInfo;
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerOutputDataReceived);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ServerErrorDataReceived);
        p.Start();

        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }

    static void ServerErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Data);
    }

    static void ServerOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Data);
    }

}
```

Does anybody know what is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens very often that normal, non-error messages are handled like errors.
You added the error handler, but didn't started it.

```
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

EDIT:
Also try WriteLine without formatting

```
Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
```